# Debugging Windows Kernel with two VirtualBox hosts

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg, windows-kernel

I'm running Linux, and I have two Windows 7 machine setup in VirtualBox.

Now I'm trying to use the first machine to debug the second one.

So I configured the same host pipe for the two machines,

[image]

In the debugger machine, I launches windbg that waiting for inputs on `COM1`:

[image]

And on the debugee machine, I enabled debug mode and reboot,

```
C:\Users\XX>bcdedit /dbgsettings
debugtype               Serial
debugport               1
baudrate                115200
```

But they don't seem to know each other, just blindly waiting.

Anything wrong? Or was it just impossible to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Uncheck "Create Pipe" on one of the VMs (for best practice it should be a debugger target). For serial port redirection one VM acts as a server (the one that creates the pipe) and other acts as a client.
- Use some terminal application to check that you can pass the data between the VMs using com port. And only then setup kernel debugger.

Comment: Unchecked Created Pipe, and selected different com port, it works now!