# Can't Break when debugging in kernel mode

Tags: windows, windbg

I'm debugging a 32-bit windows 7 machine kernel that is set up on Vmware with Windbg that is in a Windows XP SP2 setup under Vmware. The debugger attaches the windows 7 machine just fine in boot-up.

The problem is I can't break into the target machine , I tried using the break button in "Debug" like I used to do in user-mode but nothing seems to be happening.

Any solutions ?

Comment: See related issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590288/debugging-windows-kernel-with-two-virtualbox-hosts?rq=1 and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706077/i-cant-break-when-attaching-to-target-machine-in-kernel-debug-mode?rq=1 to see if they help

Answer (score 0):

i believe we would need some more details to help you here. Here is the setup as i understand

Degugee machine : Is running Win7, 32 bit.

Debuger machine : Is running XP SP2.

How are you connecting the two. Am assuming you are using pipes. Can you share those details ?

Quick suggestions

a. look up the details in "Setting up Kernel-mode deubgging ..." in the help file that comes with winDBG.

b. Hope the firewall settings are not blocking the commands being sent from the debugger machine.